# plsql procedure to take maximum of a column and increment it by 1

Tags: plsql, procedure

I have a requirement on below table wherein I need to update the  table with columns  SFX and SEQ as in first I need to take maximum of SEQ and when its value reaches 99 i need to make SFX Column value to 02 and SEQ to 01. Please help me with th plsql procedure and update commands in it to achieve this.

Output as of now

```
PROV_NTWK  PDF_PID LOC  SFX   SEQ
MGCN       100     2    01    01
MGCN       100     3    01    02
MGCN       100     23   01    99
MGCN       100     21   01    01
MGCN       50      1    01    02
```

Expected output:

```
PROV_NTWK  PDF_PID LOC  SFX   SEQ
MGCN       100     2    01    01
MGCN       100     3    01    02
MGCN       100     23   01    99
MGCN       100     21   02    01
MGCN       50      1    01    01
```

****I have written below procedure but it is just assigning max value to SEQ column and not incrementing it:****

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE trying(SEQ varchar2,SFX varchar2)
IS 
v_seq PDF_PROV.SEQ%TYPE;
v_sfx PDF_PROV.SFX%TYPE;
v_max_value number;
CURSOR HELLO IS select SEQ,SFX FROM PDF_PROV;
BEGIN
OPEN HELLO;
LOOP
FETCH HELLO INTO v_seq,v_sfx;
EXIT WHEN HELLO%NOTFOUND;
UPDATE PDF_PROV SET seq=(select max(v_seq)+1 from PDF_PROV),sfx='01';
v_max_value:=seq;
if v_max_value ='99' then
reset_sequence('hr_seq');
UPDATE PDF_PROV SET seq='hr_seq.currval',sfx='hr_seq.nextval';
end if;
END LOOP;
CLOSE HELLO;
END;
```

Comment: `v_max_value:=seq;` requires `seq` to be a variable. Probably it would be better to `select max(v_seq)+1 into v_max_value from pdf_prov;`

Comment: I can't really follow what `update pdf_prov set seq='hr_seq.currval',sfx='hr_seq.nextval';` is trying to do. Perhaps some sample data and expected results would make the issue clearer.

Comment: William as I showed in my expected output above(see the last 2 rows) i want SFX to reset to 02 and SEQ to 01 so thinking of that i used this statement. If you have better logic pls share it with me it would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed your example. However I still don't understand *'I need to take maximum of SEQ and when its value reaches 99...'* The maximum of SEQ is already 99. What do you mean by 'reaching' 99?

Comment: No that is example i showed that when by incrementing gradually it reaches 99 then column SFX should reset to 02 and SEQ to 01.

Comment: Since you have failed to provide sample input, you only provided claimed output vs desired output. We cannot really see what you want to achieve. But the posted procedure did not produce the claimed output. Neither of your updates contain a WHERE clause, so the each update modifies every row. As each update both SEQ and SFX the resulting output must have the same SEQ and SFX for every row in the table.  Could this be a copy/paste error? And it is the actually the Input instead of the current output?

Comment: Further the sub select for SEQ in the first update "max(v_seq)+1" is not doing what you expect. It is selecting the max value of a single local variable the result of which is always the value of local variable to begin with. So here it is equivalent of 'v_seq+1' where v_seq is the original value of the seq in the most recently row fetched. Not the current max within the table.